# How to clone mercurial repository created by eclipse plugin in other laptop?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, mercurial

My colleague created mercurial repository by eclispe plugin(http://javaforge.com/project/HGE)(right click project root->team->share with->mercurial....) in hist laptop with ip address:192.168.0.111,the question is how I can clone his repository use same plugin in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cloning, you need access via either ssh or http (or some other mechanism provided by a plugin). If your colleague is running a Linux or OS X system, he could run an SSH server on his box and create an account for you, so that you'd be able to clone his repository over ssh. The easier solution, which also works on Windows, is for your colleague to run `hg serve` in his Mercurial repository (I don't know if the Eclipse plugin has an option for that), which will run the embedded webserver. By default, you should then be able to clone from `http://192.168.0.111:8000/` (the `hg serve` command has options to run it on another port).